# Why are human wastes yellow?

Tags: human-physiology

Except for the feces, which is more brownish, all the human wastes (urine, earwax, snivel, phlegm, and rheum) are usually yellowish. Why is that?
I heard that urine is yellow due to bilirubin(?). What about others?

Comment: its interesting that many of the biological materials are more or less yellowish, may it be blood plasma or tree wood or curdled milk; but i cant see any significance for it. Seem to be coincidence. Or Maybe electronic structures of the molecules be a reason?

Comment: It is because of the pigment stercobiline which is present in human faeces

Comment: If your phlegm &c are yellow, you probably have a respiratory infection.